# how to sudo over vpn

Tags: ssh, sudo, vpn

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with a plain-vanilla install. The server is on a rack in the server room, and I don't have physical access to it. Fortunately `openssh` was installed on the machine.

Today, I have to install stuff on it, but the only account on the server is the default account ('admin'), and it appears that I'm unable to SSH into the box using the default account because of the ssh config file.

I was able to get someone to go into the server room and add an unpriviliged user ('scott'). I am able to SSH in as this user, but I can't figure out how to get root access.

I tried:

1. `su root` and get **Authetication Failure**
2. `su admin` and get **No passwd entry for user 'admin'**
3. `sudo moduser -aG scott` and get **scott is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.**
4. `ssh admin@localhost` and get **Permission denied, please try again.**

Any advice?

Comment: No. If the user you have access to is unprivileged i.e. has no rights to use `sudo` to run stuff as root, you can't do anything. There is no way to bypass this security measure without physical access or another, working admin account.

Comment: Maybe you just got the username "admin" wrong. It does not seem to exist on this system. Are you sure that is the correct name for the privileged account?

Comment: To get a root shell, use `sudo -i` and type in your user password. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo and https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: @SebastianStark  That was the correct answer. The username was Admin (with capital A), but in the passwd file, it was lowercased. When I used the proper case, it worked! Thanks!